# How do I get events to show up in calendar using php sql query?

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar

Edit* I have found the issue. The date is being converted to this format: **Mar 1 2018 12:00AM** I have posted my solution below.

My query returns the appropriate results, however none of the events are showing up on the calendar.

Here's what the data looks like in SQL in case there's format issues I don't know about:

**Name:** Test

**Start:** 2009-09-23 00:00:00.000

**End:**  2010-04-05 00:00:00.000

PHP:

```
$query = mssql_query("select [NAME], [Start], [End] from [database] where [Name] = 'Test'");

       $result = array();

        if (mssql_num_rows($query)) {

            while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

                $result[] = $row;
            }
        } 

        $data = array();

        foreach($result as $i => $item)
        {
         $data[] = array(
          'title'   => $item["Name"],
          'start'   => $item["Start"],
          'end'   => $item["End"]
         );
        }
```

JSON/JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 editable:true,
 header:{
 left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
},
events: <?php echo json_encode($data); ?> ,
selectable:true,
selectHelper:true,

})

});
</script>
```

Comment: Any error on the browser's console?

Comment: There is no error within the browser's console :(

Comment: Is your JSON/JS file being parsed via PHP, did you put a JSON header on it? Or is it somewhere on the PHP file?

Comment: Updated code with my header script. This is all being done within the same php file, what you cant see is the HTML. Other than that, this is all of the code... It my also be worth noting I can add events manually and they show up just fine.

Comment: " The date is being converted to this format: Mar 1 2018 12:00AM" probably because that's the default string format that SQL Server serialises dates to if you don't specify anything else. So yes you need to convert it to the format fullCalendar expects. You've done it in PHP in your answer which is fine, you can also do it in the SQL statement instead. It doesn't really matter either way.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @ADyson, please upvote and accept my answer if you don't mind. I don't want stack overflow to ban me from asking questions lol

Comment: I already did upvote. You're the only one who can accept the answer, since you asked the question. You're allowed to accept your own answers. AFAIK you wouldn't get banned unless you get a large number of downvotes, so far you haven't got any.

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason my date format was being converted, so I just converted it in the php loop:

```
<?php
foreach($result as $i => $item)
    {
     $data[] = array(
      'title'   => $item["Name"],
      'start'   => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($item["Start"]));
      'end'   => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($item["End"]));
     );
    }
?>
```